# How to get descendants that are not also descendants of a specific node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery, and I want to get all elements of a specific type that are not descendants of a particular kind of node.

E.g. my DOM is like:

```
<div id='idthatiknow'>
    <div>
        <span>good1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>good2</span>
    </div>
    <p>
        <span>bad</span>
        <div>
            <span>bad</span>
        </div>
    </p>
<div>
```

I need a selector that will get me `good1` and `good2` but not `bad`. But, I need to start at the id that I know. So I'm thinking, something like `#idthatiknow not(p) span`, but that doesn't work. Keep in mind, my actual dom is a lot more complicated - this is only a simplified example.

So, is there any way to retrieve all elements that are a descendant of X but not a descendant of Y?

Comment: `#idthatiknow > :not(p) span` Though you say the actual situation is more complicated, so who knows?

Comment: In the above surely it would just be "#idthatiknow div span"?

Comment: @BillyMoat That would bring in the last div span that contains bad. You need the `>` operator to restrict it.

Comment: @BillyMoat that will get the second `bad`.

Comment: FWIW, `<div>` can't be inside `<p>` element.

Comment: ...also, your example markup is invalid. If you're actually using invalid markup, then there are no guarantees that any selector would work properly.

Comment: @VisioN good catch on that.. didn't even notice.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, I know the markup is invalid - it's just a simplified example to give a rough idea of the approximate structure. The actual case has elements nested about 7 levels deep and is partially dynamically generated, so not possible to post here in full.

Comment: If you know the markup is invalid, then why post it as an example? Are you saying that the actual markup has this structure or not?

Comment: @cookiemonster To provide a visual example to make it easy to imagine the actual structure. I am looking for a general case, not a solution to a specific problem, so the specific details shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: A visual example that is invalid doesn't make it easy. It make it unclear. But if you simply want all elements that descend from certain direct children, but not others, then my first comment above shows how. Your original selector was close.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just filter on parents

```
$('#idthatiknow span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('p').length === 0;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N99bY/)

Note that it doesn't work on the last one, as a `DIV` can't be inside a `P`, so it's moved by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer, but then deleted it. I am reposting it, because it was correct, but out of respect for whatever reason they had for removing their answer I will not name them and will make this community wiki. If they want to post it back again I will mark it correct, otherwise I will mark this answer correct.

They posted:

```
#idthatiknow > div span { /* your styles here */}
/* all spans with a direct child of div from #idthatiknow */


#idthatiknow span:not(#idthatiknow > div span) { /* your styles here */}
/* all spans except the ones with a direct child of div from #idthatiknow */
```

The second one solves the problem for me - it allows selecting an arbitrary descendant of an arbitrary element, excluding descendants of another element.

Comment: I deleted it because it only selected the child and not the descendant, so I didn't really answer the question. :)

Comment: That solution is posted as CSS selectors instead of jQuery selectors, making it invalid because of the selector given to `:not()`. Not to mention that it's unnecessarily complex, and doesn't do what you described.

Comment: @cookiemonster That's what I thought as well, but I tried it in jquery and it worked

Comment: @mister_rampage It's trivial to remove the '>' to make it descendant instead of child. The question was hot to select an element descending from X but not Y, and `X e:not(Y e)` does so.

Comment: @Benubird Sure, I'm just saying that as a CSS selector it doesn't work. jQuery uses non-standard selectors.